# SQL Query ; I want to get Enquiry_No which has not been updated since last 7 days

Tags: sql-server

I am having two tables TblEnquiry with Enquiry _No as Primary Key and tblHistory for maintaing updatiing details with Enquiry_No as foreign key and History_CreatedOn field for date.
I want to get Enquiries which have not been updated since last 7 days.

Comment: I presume the relationship between TblEnquiry and TblHistory is one-to-many?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using SQL Server:

```
SELECT
     <add columns here>
FROM
     tblEnquiry
WHERE
     NOT EXISTS
     (
          SELECT *
          FROM tblHistory H
          WHERE H.enquiry_no = E.enquiry_no
            AND H.history_createdon BETWEEN DATEADD(dy, -7, GETDATE()) AND GETDATE()
     )
```

Comment: Why the BETWEEN?  Why not just >= DATEADD(DAY, -7, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) ?

Comment: It avoids a situation where there is a date in the future. Ideally the column has a constraint on it that prevents that, but just in case...

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT e.*
FROM tblEnquiry e
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM tblHistory h WHERE e.Enquiry_No = e.Enquiry_No AND h.History_CreatedOn >= DATEADD(dd, -7, GETDATE())
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH Hist(enquiry_no, history_createdon) AS
(
    SELECT Enquiry_No, History_CreatedOn
    FROM tblHistory
    WHERE History_CreatedOn >= DATEADD(dd, -7, GETDATE())
)
SELECT * 
FROM tblEnquiry 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Hist ON tblHist.enquiry_no = tblEnquiry.enquiry_no 
WHERE tblHistory.enquiry_no IS NULL
```

This will avoid the poor performance of the standard NOT EXISTS query

Comment: OP wants enquiries not updated in last 7 days...this will find enquiries without any history

Comment: *What* poor performance of NOT EXISTS? http://explainextended.com/2009/09/15/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-sql-server/ -1 for not understanding SQL

Comment: Edited to reflect AdaTheDev's comment... as for the poor performance of NOT EXISTS, that's experience

Comment: By all means, test which performs well for you in any given scenario, but the generalisation that performance of NOT EXISTS being poor, full stop, is wrong. The article referenced by @gbn is a very good article - well worth a read - and actually demonstrates the opposite.

Comment: most likely the plans for LEFT JOIN, NOT IN and NOT EXISTS will be exactly the same...maybe during the SQL Server 7 days this was the case but since 2000 I really haven't run into this myself..not saying it can't happen

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer

select h1.Enquiry_No 
from tblHistory h1
group by h1.Enquiry_No
having DATEDIFF(DD,Max(h1.History_CreatedOn),GETDATE())>=7

I got the Enquiries that have not been updated since last 7 days